# Resize the full image proportionally (dynamically but without fixed image dimensions) to div container without stretching to each side of container

Tags: html, css, image, wordpress

I have a problem with resizing the full size image proportionally without stretching that are dynamically generated and loaded into fixed container. I am using Wordpress + WP Ecommerce to dynamically resize the full singke

Say for example with the following html code:

```
<div class="image" style="display: table; width:360px; height: 430px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden; text-align:center;">
       <table width="100%"  class='nocolour' style="display: table-cell;margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; height:auto;">
           <tr style=" width:100%;">
           <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle; width:100%; text-align: center;">
           <div class="imageplaceholder" style="max-width:100%; width:100%; height: 430px; overflow: hidden;margin: auto; text-align:center; "><a style="width: 100%; text-align: center; " href="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_permalink(); ?>">
                 <img style="height: auto; max-width:100%;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display:block; overflow:hidden;"  class="product_image" id="product_image_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" alt="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_thumbnail(get_option('product_image_width'),get_option('product_image_height'),'','single'); ?>"/>
             </a></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and the css :

```
.wrapper .page-container .content .rightcontent .main-product-image img{
   width: 360px; height:430px; display:block; overflow:hidden;
}
```

any ideas to rectifiy the problem?

Any reply is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Setting both width and height parameters will stretch and distort your images to fit those dimensions. Set either the width or height (whichever you prefer) in your CSS to "auto". So:

```
.wrapper .page-container .content .rightcontent .main-product-image img{
    width: 360px; height:auto; display:block; overflow:hidden;
}
```

Secondly, make sure that none of your images are LESS than the provided static styles. In this case, none of the images should be any smaller than 360px in width. The general rule of thumb when it comes to scaling images in the browser is to always scale DOWN. Otherwise, your image is going to look like a smashed butthole.

As far as the styles of the image's parent containers, it doesn't look too bad. You have a static width and height, and it cuts off any overflow. Just make sure that when images are scaled down to their respective static value, that the auto value isn't less than the dimensions of the container.